# Get element's scroll position relative to ancestor

Tags: javascript

I know that you can get an element's scroll position relative to its `offsetParent` by using `element.offsetTop`. You can also get its scroll position relative to the window by using `element.getBoundingClientRect().top`.

Is there any way to get an element's scroll position relative to an arbitrary ancestor? We can assume that this ancestor is the only scrolling element on the page.

EDIT: we can't use jQuery, and it's for an Angular 2 application.

Comment: if you are willing to use jQuery, there is a `.scrollTop()` method

Comment: @McHat Unfortunately jQuery is out of the question.

Comment: ... then probably you will have to write a recursive method that crawls the DOM and uses the `offsetTop` property of each element along the way to calculate the position